# Improve post-notice for sourceless answers

Tags: feature-request, status-review, answers, wording, post-notices

On questions like [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/402630/a-fun-catchy-way-to-say-the-opposite-of-a-no-brainer) that have  a tendency to be answered by low-rep users who don't cite any sources, mods can add the following post-notice:

> Want to improve this post? Provide detailed answers to this question, including citations and an explanation of why your answer is correct. Answers without enough detail may be edited or deleted.

It's a useful banner, but the issue is that the same notice is posted over *answers* that don't cite any sources. The wording of the notice, however, remains geared toward questions. One issue in the wording is that the 'your' implies that it's addressed to the post-owner, not any random editor. Here is a proposed rewording for the post-notice on sourceless answers:

> Want to improve this answer? Add details and include citations to explain why this answer is correct. Answers without enough detail may be edited or deleted.

Comment: There's already a different post notice which explicitly asks for citations (example: [answer to: "What does the 'Reset' button on an N64 actually do?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/554787/93396)). Post notices are something that can be customized on a per-site basis, so it's unclear if you're asking to change this across all of SE or just on one site.

Answer (score 7):

Arguably the bug is that a moderator is allowed to apply a post notice with a description that starts with "This question" to not-a-question. The following are available on all SE sites, and "Needs citation" is more appropriate for answers:

> - Needs citation
>   This post contains content that needs citations from reputable sources.
> - Current event
>   This post relates to a rapidly changing event.
> - Needs detailed answers
>   This question needs detailed answers, including citations and an explanation of why an answer is correct.

([From the mod "add post notice" prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sela8.png))